# MySQL GROUP BY with two counts

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with two columns that I am interested in, created_at and total_time.
I want to perform a query which groups the records by the day of the week they were created, counting the total count and also the count where total_time > 5.

For example if there are 6 records on a Friday, and 4 of them have a time > 5, the query should return this for the Friday:

Friday | 6 | 4

I have the day and the count > 5 working like this:

```
SELECT
DAYNAME(created_at) as weekday,
COUNT(*) AS count
FROM my_table
WHERE
total_time > 5
GROUP BY weekday
ORDER BY count DESC
```

But is there a way to get the total count included too (regardless of the total_time)?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get both counts but using the following:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(created_at) as weekday,
  COUNT(*) AS count,
  sum(case when total_time > 5 then 1 else 0 end) TimeOver5
FROM my_table
GROUP BY weekday
ORDER BY count DESC
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55218/1).

This uses an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the rows where the `total_time >5`